# Calling parent class member function from derived class

Tags: c++, c++11

I am new to C++ and have a code with several classes. I want to access member function of parent class from derived class. So I defined public inheritance and calling a member function, but getting error `expected unqualified-id before ‘.’ token A.f1()`.

```
#include <iostream>

class A
{
    public:
    void f1 ()
    {
        std::cout<<"In class A::f1()";
    }
};

class B:public A
{
    public:
    void f2()
    {
        std::cout<<"In class B::f2() \n";
        std::cout<<"Calling A::f1() \n";
        A.f1(); //Error
    }
};


int main()
{
    B obj1;
    obj1.f2();

    return 0;
}
```

In the above scenario, to access `f1()` from `B::f2()` is public inheritance the only and recommended way?

Comment: use this instead: A::f1()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to call

```
f1();
```

or if your derived class has its own f1 funciton (overriding) call

```
A::f1();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
A.f1(); //Error
```

with

```
f1(); // Success!!
```

Comment: Nice comment :)